# Uso di ne come complemento di termine

Tags: grammar, particles

Nel seguente [titolo di giornale](http://www.corriere.it/economia/14_aprile_29/bonus-chi-ne-ha-diritto-chi-no-niente-domanda-automatico-e467bd96-cf69-11e3-bf7e-201ea72c5359.shtml) l'uso della particella *ne* non mi pare corretto (ma posso sbagliarmi):

> Bonus, chi ne ha diritto e chi no

Personalmente avrei scritto: "chi *vi* ha diritto e chi no".

Chiedo quindi lumi sull'uso di *ne* come complemento di termine (sempre che di complemento di termine si tratti).

Comment: Stai suggerendo che "ne" vale "di esso" mentre "vi" vale "ad esso". E visto che si ha diritto "ad esso", non "di esso", parrebbe essere più corretto dire che "vi si ha il diritto", non che "se ne ha il diritto".

Comment: «Ho tutto il diritto di farlo» ---> «**Ne** ho tutto il diritto». «Ho diritto alla pensione» ---> «**Vi** ho diritto» (o anche «**Ne** ho diritto»?)

Comment: un commento a freddo: io avrei scritto 'bonus: chi ha diritto e chi no' omettendo la particella. come titolo di giornale il significato e' chiaro, conciso e immediato.

Answer (score 5):

Corretto, in questo caso "ne" è complemento di termine. A seconda della frase potrebbe essere anche un complemento di specificazione, di moto da luogo ecc.

Non vedo niente di sbagliato nel suo utilizzo nella frase citata. Evitare di usarlo significherebbe dover trasformare la frase in

> Bonus, chi ha diritto a ciò e chi no

oppure

> Bonus, chi ha diritto al bonus e chi no

o altre frasi orrende del genere.

**Aggiornamento**
Effettivamente, usare "vi" parrebbe più corretto dal punto di vista grammaticale. Secondo me, però, suona molto (troppo?) ricercato al giorno d'oggi, mentre "ne" suona più naturale. Forse uno di quei casi in cui la lingua parlata porta a modificare la lingua in generale?

Comment: E tuttavia, dopo l'osservazione di Walter Tross, "chi **[vi](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vi1/)** ha diritto e chi no" suona decisamente meglio, non credi?

Comment: @randomatlabuser dopo aver letto il commento effettivamente sembrerebbe più corretto grammaticalmente. Che suoni Decisamente meglio, invece, non sono propriamente d'accordo :D

Comment: Infatti non sono sicuro che la particella "ne" possa essere usata per costruire il complemento di termine.

Comment: @randomatlabuser risposta aggiornata, grazie per il suggerimento :)

Comment: Meglio, devo però dire che, almeno alle mie orecchie, il "ne" in questo caso stona un po'. È pur vero che si ha "diritto di (+ verbo)" e "diritto a (+ sostantivo)" e questo può contribuire ad aumentare la confusione.

Comment: @randomatlabuser vero vero :)

Comment: La versióne con "vi" suona decisamente male ....

Comment: @Bruno9779, non sono d'accordo. Sto cominciando a pensare al "vi" come ad una specie in pericolo di estinzione. Spero di non dovervi rinunciare, un giorno... ;-)

Comment: In quanto pronome personale, _ne_ non ha altre funzioni se non quella di partitivo («_Ne_ voglio due etti»), di complemento d’argomento («_Ne_ parliamo piú tardi»), di complemento di specificazione («_Ne_ sono divenuto amico»), di provenienza («Non _ne_ ho mai ottenuto risposta»). (Tralascio gli altri casi particolari, in cui assume un valore pleonastico o idiomatico.) Si parafrasa dunque in _di ciò_ (_lui_/_lei_/_questo_/_quello_, ecc.) o _da ciò_ (_lui_/_lei_/_questo_/_quello_, ecc.). Nella frase in questione l'estensione di _ne_ al dativo sarebbe un arbitrio, dunque.

Comment: La frase va dunque rianalizzata: chi ha il diritto di (fare) qualcosa.

Answer (score 2):

In «Aver*ne* il diritto» *ne* non è un dativo. *Diritto* non regge solamente la preposizione *a*, ma anche *di*, sia in proposizioni all’infinito («il diritto *di* fare qualcosa») sia nel semplice complemento di specificazione («diritto *di* prelazione», «diritto *d*’intervento», ecc.). *Ne* mantiene dunque il suo significato: «Avere il diritto *di ciò*».